# Method overloading C#

Tags: c#, methods, overloading

I'm new to C# and trying to figure out how i can easily implement the following:

I have a subscriber:

```
public interface ISubscriber
{
    void HandleMessage(IMessage message);
}

class TriggerSubscriber : ISubscriber
{
    public void HandleMessage(IMessage message)
    {
         //This will be called by default   
    }
    public void HandleMessage(TriggerMessage message)
    {
         //This won't work, why?    
    }
}
```

Trying to handle the following message:

```
public class TriggerMessage : IMessage
{
    string identifier { get; set; }

    public TriggerMessage(string triggerIdentifier)
    {
        identifier = triggerIdentifier;
    }
}

public interface IMessage
{

}
```

I expected that the following would have been called:

```
public void HandleMessage(TriggerMessage message)
```

instead of

```
public void HandleMessage(IMessage message)
```

with

```
ISubscriber trigger = new TriggerSUbscriber();
trigger.HandleMessage(
    new TriggerMessage()
);
```

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `trigger` variable is defined as it being of type `ISubscriber` (no matter what the actual object type is). `ISubscriber` only has one method signature:

```
void HandleMessage(IMessage message);
```

So the compiler calls that method.

In fact, if you did this:

```
class TriggerSubscriber : ISubscriber
{
  public void HandleMessage(IMessage message)
  {
  }
  public void HandleMessage(int something)
  {
  }
}
```

And then try to do this:

```
ISubscriber trigger = new TriggerSubscriber();
trigger.HandleMessage(4);
```

The compiler will complain that there's no such method in `ISubscriber` which takes an `int` parameter.

There are three options:

1. Add the specific `TriggerMessage` method to the interface
2. Declare your `trigger` variable as `TriggerSubscriber`, instead of as `ISubscriber`, or cast it to `TriggerSubscriber` when calling `HandleMessage`:

   ```
   ((TriggerSubscriber)trigger).HandleMessage(new TriggerMessage());
   ```
3. Solve it in the implementation:

   ```
   class TriggerSubscriber : ISubscriber
   {
       public void HandleMessage(IMessage message)
       {
         var triggerMessage = message as TriggerMessage;
         if(triggerMessage != null)
         {
            // Casting is not necessary, but I'd still put it
            // here just to make it clear
            HandleMessage((TriggerMessage)triggerMessage);
            return;
         }
         // other code
       }
       public void HandleMessage(TriggerMessage message)
       {
       }
   }
   ```

I'd definitely use #3 (and I'd call the method that receives a `TriggerMessage` something like `HandleTriggerMessage`, instead of having possible ambiguities), but you choose

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really clearly described. Not as elegant as i hoped but this will do

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `trigger` is of type `ISubscriber` which only has one `HandleMessage` method defined in its interface:

```
void HandleMessage(IMessage message)
```

There is no other method to match from the interface definition, so that only visible method is called. There is no overload resolution taking place here.

If you change `ISubscriber trigger` to `TriggerSubscriber trigger` (now there are two methods visible!) you will see you get the expected method called.